# Rails - Create array for Highcharts Chart data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

Im trying to plot out a highcharts chart. I would like datatime on the x-axis and count on the y axis. What I have so far:

```
series: [{
name: 'Success',
pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
pointStart: <%= DateTime.strptime(params[:start_date], '%m/%d/%Y').at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
data: <%= ServerStatus.success.find(:all, :select => 'generated_at, count', :conditions => {:generated_at => DateTime.strptime("07/25/2013", '%m/%d/%Y').beginning_of_day..DateTime.strptime("07/25/2013", '%m/%d/%Y').end_of_day}, :order => 'generated_at ASC').to_json %>
```

Which generates:

> data:
>   [{"count":2222,"generated_at":"2013-07-25T00:00:00Z"},{"count":65,"generated_at":"2013-07-25T00:00:00Z"},{"count":335,"generated_at":"2013-07-25T00:00:00Z"},{"count":320,"generated_at":"2013-07-25T00:00:00Z"},{"count":156,"generated_at":"2013-07-25T00:00:00Z"}]

How can I format this in the way which highcharts expects, which I believe is `[datetime, count]`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a variable before the definition of the series:

```
array_of_records = ServerStatus.success.find(:all, :select => 'generated_at, count', :conditions => {:generated_at => DateTime.strptime("07/25/2013", '%m/%d/%Y').beginning_of_day..DateTime.strptime("07/25/2013", '%m/%d/%Y').end_of_day}, :order => 'generated_at ASC').to_json
```

and then, inside the series definition, define data as follows:

```
data: <%= array_of_records.map { |record| [record["generated_at"], record["count"]] } %>
```